# How to print out __str__ for each instance of a class in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a playlist of songs, and I would like to create an instance of the class SongData for each song in the playlist. I have code that isn't included that extracts the song name, artist, and song directory from the playlist. For the purposes of this question I have included these as 3 lists, songNames, artistNames, dirNames.

```
class SongData(object):
    def __init__(self, title="", artist="", directory=""):
        self.title, self.artist, self.directory = title, artist, directory
    def __str__(self):
        desc_str = "Title: %s \nArtist: %s \nDirectory: %s \n" %(self.title,
                                            self.artist, self.directory)
        print desc_str

songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
artistNames = ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']
dirNames = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']

songs = {name: SongData(title=name) for name in songNames}
artists = {band: SongData(artist=band) for band in artistNames}
directorys = {direc: SongData(directory=direc) for direc in dirNames}
```

I would like to be able to print out the desc_str for each song so it appears like this:

```
Title: song1 
Artist: artist1 
Directory: dir1
```

But so far I have only managed to call one data category at once, so it prints Title: song1 but leaves the `Artist:` and `Directory:` sections blank. I have been using:

```
print songs['song1']
print artists['artist1']
```

How can I get it to print them out all at once? I think the problem is that I am only referencing the data in each dictionary, not calling the instance of the class relevant to that song.

When I do it simply and manually, as follows, it works, but I cannot figure out how to put this into a loop so it will work for the lists `songNames`, `artistNames`, `dirNames`.

```
p = SongData('song1', 'artist1', 'dir1')
p.__str__()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SongData` class needs to `return` from the `__str__` function:

```
class SongData(object):
    def __init__(self, title="", artist="", directory=""):
        self.title, self.artist, self.directory = title, artist, directory
    def __str__(self):
        desc_str = "Title: %s \nArtist: %s \nDirectory: %s \n" %(self.title,
                                            self.artist, self.directory)
        return desc_str # <------ RETURN HERE
```

Then, you can build up instances of `SongData` as such:

```
songNames = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
artistNames = ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']
dirNames = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']

songdata = [SongData(*params) for params in zip(songNames, artistNames, dirNames)]
```

Note that the above is a list-comp that given the above 3 lists is effectively equivalent to:

```
songdata = [
    SongData('song1', 'artist1', 'dir1'),
    SongData('song2', 'artist2', 'dir2'),
    SongData('song3', 'artist3', 'dir3')
]
```

Then loop over those, and use `print` to get the result of your `__str__`:

```
for song in songdata:
    print song
```

Gives you:

```
Title: song1 
Artist: artist1 
Directory: dir1 

Title: song2 
Artist: artist2 
Directory: dir2 

Title: song3 
Artist: artist3 
Directory: dir3
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `SongData(*params)` unzipping the `params` for use as arguments in `SongData` ?

Comment: @NickCamps it's called, "unpacking" but yup you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

Or it is also possible to print a `for` loop within the `__str__` function and then return empty string.

```
def __str__(self):
    for item in self.UserClasses:
        print item
    return ""
```

This works like a charm for me. Although might not be the best practice.